# How to Copy a file whose path comes from another file?

Tags: c#, wpf, file, exception

Good afternoon,
I'd like to firstly apologize for my beginner ways, but I've tried to make a file which its sole purpose is to store a single line (a path) in order to save it for later use, without having to type it over and over.

The writing and reading from said file go well, except when I try to copy another file using that file's path. My intents are to save a path in that file so that the main course of the program (which is to copy files into said path). However, I am met with the File.Copy exception claiming the path has illegal characters in it. I've tried multiple solutions, including changing the path formatting itself, to no avail.

If it helps, here's the event for the button to write said file:

```
string filepath = @"C:\test folder\file.txt";
string pathinfile = @"C:\test folder\test subfolder"; //directories created previously

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(pathinfile);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("File Written.");
```

And here's the code for the event that reads the file, prints it through a Messagebox then tries to copy the file into a subfolder.

```
        //Read the File
        string filepath = @"C:\test folder\file.txt";
        string readpath = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
        MessageBox.Show(readpath);
        //Write to the file's indicated location
        File.Copy(filepath, Path.Combine(readpath, "copied file.txt")); //illegal characters
```

This however just breaks the program and throws the exception. Is it something I'm doing wrong, that I shouldn't  *clearly* be doing but still am? Or is there a better way to store data that's easier to make read? I appreciate any and all help provided, thank you.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `readpath` when you debug the program? What is the **exact** value of `Path.Combine(readpath, "copied file.txt")`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the full text. 

System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.'

Comment: I'm sorry for the eventual late response - I'm trying to fetch the exact value, and since I'm not very good at this, I don't have much clue on how to do it. I'd like to thank you for your attention in the meantime.

Comment: I've found the Immediate Window - and when I write 'readpath' it gives me *"@\"C:\\test folder\\test subfolder\"\r\n"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I've replaced ReadAllText with ReadAllLines and implemented it in an array. It works as it should now.

Comment: You write in the file using WriteLine. That adds a NewLine character chat causes your problem. You can use only Write to put the data in the file. Also, if your issue is solved, mark the answer as Solved.

Comment: Thank you, but StackOverflow won't let me mark the answer yet, need to wait a couple more days.